# How can get character from ASCII(ascii>127 && ascii<255) in iOS

Tags: ios, ascii

In iOS project,I want to get data from php server, and it used authcode to encrypt，question is how can I get the character from ASCII(ascii>127 && ascii<255),  in iOS?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with php. Removing tag.

Comment: just to note the server used AUTHCODE

Answer (score 1):

You can get like this..

```
NSString *string = @"A";
int asciiValue = [string characterAtIndex:0]; // 65

if(asciiValue > 127 || asciiValue < 255)
{
    NSLog(@"Data Exists"); 
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Data not Exists"); 
}
```

You can print ascii value from 127 to 255 using this code

```
for(int i = 127 ; i < 255 ; i++)
{
     NSLog(@"Ascii %c",i);
}
```

Comment: it can not handle my question, I want to get the character from asciiValue ,and the asciiValue is between 127-255

Comment: You wanna value between 127 and 255 then see my edited answer.

Comment: yeah,it can get character with your answer,but the character can not math that from php,e.g. 255,I want to get ÿ

Comment: to get the right character and it can matched value from php's chr()

Comment: You need to check ascii value not character.

Comment: the ascii value is matched

Answer (score 0):

First, ASCII contains only chars from 0x1 to 0x127. It's a 7 bit code. Values above 127 are not ascii

---

It is hard to get what you want to do. But this may help anyway: If you need to convert a byte value to it's "literal" representation - in the current 8 bit codepage e.g. ISO-85xx - use the function `chr()` :

(*PHP code, not sure whether you wanted that, I see now that the php tag was removed*):

```
for($i = 128; $i < 255; $i++) {
    echo chr($i);
}
```

Note again, that the output will depend on the codepage which is currently used

Comment: well, I mean is there any function in iOS like your method

Comment: Sorry, I have no android. Would really like to help otherwise. I answered because you tagged the question as php first :)